Is this okay for round robin schedule without using queue?
trying to understand more about round robin but I don't know if this is the right way to implement it.
// Keep iterating until all processes are completed
while (completedProcesses < n) {
    boolean anyProcessExecuted = false; // Flag to track if any process executed in this time unit
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arrivalTime.get(i) <= currentTime && remainingTime[i] > 0) { // Process can be started
            anyProcessExecuted = true; // Set the flag to true indicating at least one process executed
            int executionTime = Math.min(quantum, remainingTime[i]); // Determine execution time for the process
            remainingTime[i] -= executionTime; // Update remaining time
            for (int j = 0; j < executionTime; j++) { // Print execution timeline
                System.out.print(processNames.get(i) + " ");
            }
            currentTime += executionTime; // Update current time
            if (remainingTime[i] == 0) { // Process completed
                completionTime[i] = currentTime; // Set completion time
                completedProcesses++; // Increment completed processes count
            }
        }
    }
    // If no process executed in this time unit, move the current time forward
    if (!anyProcessExecuted) {
        currentTime++;
    }


I think there is something not right in the while loop when this line
if (arrivalTime.get(i) <= currentTime && remainingTime[i] > 0) execute

no - that inner for loop is just busy waiting.  And from the sample code, it looks like all processes were already started?  Do you really mean round robin?  Maybe you mean throttling?

i tried to run it with my sample and got some error as running at t=6 instead of D but it returned B, but could not figure out where.
A   0   3
B   2   6
C   4   4
D   6   5
E   8   2
expected output: A A B A B C B D C B E D C B E D C B D D  (Correct one)
output generated:A A B A B C D B C D E B C D E B C D B D    (Wrong one)

It would probably be helpful for you to step through the code line by line using a debugger.
